# mysql optimization: current & previous orders should be on different tables, or same table with a flag column?

Tags: database-design, mysql, query-optimization

I want to know what's the most optimized way to work with mysql.

I have a quite large database for orders. i have another table for previous orders, whenever the order is completed, it's erased from orders and is moved to previous orders.

should i keep using this mothod or put them all in the same table and add a column that flags if it's current or previous orders?

kfir